# What does "Then must not existence be revealed to her(the soul) in thought, if at all" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The quoted passage is from [Plato's Phaedo](http://classics.mit.edu/Plato/phaedo.html). Is it correct to group the sentence in boldface as *"Then must (not existence) be revealed to her in thought, if at all?"* ?

I think it means that Socrates asked, must the soul know nonexistence only by thought. Am I correct?

> Then when does the soul attain truth?-for in attempting to consider anything in company with the body she is obviously deceived.
>
> Yes, that is true.
>   **Then must not existence be revealed to her in thought, if at all?**
>
> Yes.
>
> And thought is best when the mind is gathered into herself and none of these things trouble her-neither sounds nor sights nor pain nor any pleasure-when she has as little as possible to do with the body, and has no bodily sense or feeling, but is aspiring after being?

Comment: I will interpret it as *Then, if [anything] at all, existence must not be revealed to her in thought*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [*Rhetorical question*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question) - a statement phrased as a question.

First, let's reroll this into modern syntax.

> Then isn't the existence revealed to [the soul] in thought, if at all?

Next, let's remove rethorical question form:

> If the existence is revealed at all, then it is revealed to the soul in thought.

The essence is that the ideas of existence can be only discovered through thought - introspection. That doesn't guarantee they will be revealed at all, but if a way exists, this is it. Self-discovery through bodily experiences is only misguiding.

Comment: +1 But I don't think it's *quite* fair to Plato to characterize his dialectic as "rhetorical". It's contrived, to be sure; but he at least makes an effort to contrive his essays as genuine inquiries.

Answer (score 4):

*Must* here has the ‘epistemic’ or inferential sense of *follow  by logical necessity, necessarily be true*.

The *not* modifies *must*; but this is an interrogative *not*, so it does not really negate *must* so much as invite assent to *must*. *Must not...?* may be paraphrased “Does it not follow by logical necessity that...?” and the sentence may be paraphrased:

> Then doesn’t it necessarily follow that existence is revealed to her [only] in thought, if [it is revealed to her] at all?